# Get list of tags for a Changeset object in JavaHg?

Tags: java, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, javahg

Is there a way to get the list of tags for a [`Changeset` object](http://javahg.aragost.com/apidocs/com/aragost/javahg/Changeset.html) in [JavaHg](http://javahg.org/)?

Comment: I'm one of the authors of JavaHg. This question was asked to us in private and we're trying to collect such questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all tags with the TagsCommand

```
Map<String,Changeset> tagMap = TagsCommand.on(repo).execute();
```

You will then have to iterate over the map and search for the Changeset in question.